# Selenium Grid Concurrent Execution: How many concurrent browsers per node?

Tags: selenium, concurrency, grid

I'm setting up a new selenium grid and I'm trying to get an accurate estimation of how many concurrent browsers I can have running per node. The goal is to take a large suite of regression, smoke, and unit tests set up with Jenkins for continuous integration. Based on the number of tests we have and the time it would take to run, I'm looking to get between 80-100 tests running concurrently. How many browsers can a single node to run concurrently? Also, is it safe to assume that the number of browsers per node is limited by processing power and memory? I have the ability to get VMs as needed but I can't find the documentation specifying this requirement which I'll need if I'm requesting more than a few VMs.

Comment: You didn't specify the programming language but I'm guessing Java? (You should add the relevant tag to your question). The default for NUnit (C#) is 1 browser per processor core. Assuming 8 cores, that would be 10-13 VMs to get 80-100 tests running concurrent. We use TFS (we're a .NET shop) and it only runs 4 browsers per VM but we didn't have to deal with setting up grid.

Answer (score 0):

Maximizing the number of browsers per node is largely dependent on both the specs of your node and tests. There is no good way to answer this, without empirically determining the correct answer through experimentation. Keep adding browsers to your nodes until there is no more benefit to doing so. Steve McConnell does a great job of discussing this in [Code Complete 2nd Ed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) in chapters 25 and 26, where he discusses code tuning strategies and techniques. It's the same principle at work - don't optimize without measuring the performance benefit of doing so. Additionally, if you're expecting to use multiple nodes, just provision one VM first, measure the number of browsers you can fit, and extrapolate from there.